# How to treat different orders as same thing in pandas or excel?

Tags: excel, pandas

[As you can see in this excel image games, strategy, board in the genres column and games, board strategy is also written in the column. The order of all these genres can be different.What command can I do to treat them as one? I need to plot this data on pandas. Please help, any command for pandas or on Excel will help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLMJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't worry about efficiency too much. This should work.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['Game,Strategy,Card,Entertainment','Game,Card,Entertainment,Strategy','Game,Card']
})
df['b']=df['name'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: sorted(x)).str.join(',')

df
```